# PHP: How to use preg_match() here?

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-match, preg-match-all

I  have two strings like

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 10303 )
```

and

```
 stdClass Object ( [error] => not found )
```

How do I catch `id` and `error` via `preg_match()` the function? I've used this code but it didn't help:

```
$file = 'stdClass Object ( [id] => 10303 )';
preg_match('/\[id\] \=\> ([0-9]+)/', $file, $mfc);
var_dump($mfc);
```

Comment: How come that you have such strings? Those obviously are objects that _somehow_ got converted if you _really_ have such strings in a variable. Wouldn't it make sense to check how that came to be? Because parsing some message from such a string sound like a really bad workaround...

Comment: Those look like objects.  Have you thought about using them as such? Or you really stuck with strings?  Also, check match or capture value like '10303'?

Comment: And what do you mean by "it didn't help"? When I try your code it appears to be working as expected... So what is your actual question here?

Comment: im trying to some api and their response is quite messy, I asked them to repair their response but they didn't . now i want to capture the id and error. or tell me how do i parse those object strings to convert them to array or object again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `error` you can use this!

```
preg_match('/\[error\][\s]*\=\>[\s]*(.*?)\?/', $file, $mfc);
var_dump($mfc);
```

And for `ID`

```
$syntax = '/\[id\][\s]*\=\>[\s]*([0-9]+)/';
preg_match($syntax, $file, $mfc);
var_dump($mfc);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### *Id*

```
preg_match('/\[id\][\s]*\=\>[\s]*([0-9]+)/', $file, $mfc);
```

---

#### *Error Text*

```
preg_match('/\[error\][\s]*\=\>[\s]*(.*?)\?/', $file, $mfc);
```

---

The main change to your regex is to take into account any unprecedented whitespace characters present.